# What does $\mathcal{ E}(|h|^2)$, where $|h|^2$ is power of the channel gain $h$ represent?

Tags: self-study, channel

I came across this notation of $\mathcal{E}(|h|^2)$ in a [research article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8931547).

$h$ is the channel gain of a wireless communication channel. In particular, a Rayleigh fading channel.

I know that $|h|^2$ denotes the power of the channel gain.

But what is that *epsilon*-like function, namely $\mathcal{E}(\cdot)$, doing to the power of the channel gain?

Similarly, the article also mentions that $\mathcal{E}(R_{\text{sum}})$ denotes the closed-form expression for the sum-rate.

Could anyone explain to me what the $\mathcal{E}(\cdot)$ function is?

Comment: might  $\mathcal E$ simply be the *expectation*?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think you might actually be right. They state this "*In this letter, we consider the case that the BS only has the knowledge of the large-scale fading of every radio link involved; or in other words, the **average channel gain** or the channel quality indicator (CQI), as considered in many practical systems.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Marcus says, it's the expectation:

$$ \mathcal{E}(|h|^2) = \int |h|^2 p_{|h|^2}(|h|^2) d|h|^2$$

where $p_{|h|^2}(|h|^2)$ is the probability density function of $|h|^2$.

This assumes that there's some randomness to the $h$ values, and the expectation gets the average value of $|h|^2$.

The mean of a variable $x$ is:

$$ \mathcal{E}(x) = \int x p_x(x) dx = \bar{x}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @nashynash you're welcome! I think I stole from, Marcus though. :(